# How to compile a .drl file through an ant build script

Tags: ant, drools

I am new to Drools. I want to know if it is possible to compile a .drl file using some kind of a command that can be entered in the windows command line (shell/cmd). I looked through the binaries that come with the drools distribution but I am unable to figure out a way to compile a .drl file.
The reason I am interested in such a command is that I want to write an ant build file which will compile my java classes and rules and create a jar. This jar should be self sufficient, i.e running the jar from the command line should run the main program, which passes facts in the session causing the rules that operate on these facts to automatically be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DroolsCompilerAntTask` used to be the way to do this. It would take all your various rule files and compile them into a serialized file. It appears to have some bugs in 5.3 though which I am currently trying to work out. In the meantime, here is an illustrative build file that can be used for creating an executable JAR based on Drools. The build will fail if the rules cannot be compiled.

```
<project name="DroolsProto" default="dist" basedir=".">
  <property name="build.src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.target" location="target"/>
  <property name="build.dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="build.artifact" value="droolsproto"/>
  <property name="one-jar.dist.dir" value="~/Work/Data/Misc/OneJar"/>   
  <property name="one-jar.version" value="0.97"/>
  <property name="one-jar.ant.jar" value="${one-jar.dist.dir}/one-jar-ant-task-${one-jar.version}.jar"/>

  <path id="build.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="${build.src}/lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <taskdef name="one-jar" classname="com.simontuffs.onejar.ant.OneJarTask"
      classpath="${one-jar.ant.jar}" onerror="report"/>

  <taskdef name="droolscompiler" classname="org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask">
    <classpath refid="build.lib.path"/>
  </taskdef> 

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.target}"/>
    <delete dir="${build.dist}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.target}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dist}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.target}/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="${build.src}/main/java" destdir="${build.target}/classes">
      <classpath refid="build.lib.path"/>
      <include name="**/*.java"/>
      <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="verify-rules">
    <droolscompiler srcDir="${build.src}/main/resources" toFile="${build.target}/classes/foo.foo">
      <classpath refid="build.lib.path"/>
    </droolscompiler>
  </target>

  <target name="verify-resources" depends="verify-rules"/>

  <target name="bundle-resources" depends="verify-resources">
    <copy todir="${build.target}/classes">
      <fileset dir="${build.src}/main/resources"/>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile, bundle-resources">
    <one-jar destfile="${build.dist}/${build.artifact}.jar">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="One-Jar-Main-Class" value="org.drools.examples.HelloWorldExample"/>
      </manifest>
      <main>
        <fileset dir="${build.target}/classes"/>
      </main>
      <lib>
        <fileset dir="${build.src}/lib">
          <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
      </lib>
    </one-jar>
  </target>
</project>
```

Note that the build uses [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) in order to create the self-contained executable, you may wish to substitute this with your 'Super Jar™' tool of choice. There is also a `DroolsVerifierAntTask` which allegedly can check logical errors in your rules (as opposed to syntactical ones), but I have no hands on experience with it.

Comment: This could be the answer I was looking for. Going to try this out and post back the result here soon. I have currently put the drools project aside for a bit as I am working on another project with strict deadlines!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
private static void compile(final String srcFile, final String destFile) throws IOException {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

    URL src = FormChecker.class.getResource(srcFile);
    Resource r = ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(src.openStream());

    kbuilder.add(r, ResourceType.DRL);
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can not initialize Drools: " + kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }
    Collection<KnowledgePackage> kpackages = kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages();

    File dest = new File(destFile);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
    out.writeObject(kpackages);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: I have already done something similar by creating a KnowledgeBuilder and calling builder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(r), ResourceType.DRL,"my_rule_file.drl"). Does this mean my rule files are going to be compiled by the class that contains this code? This means that when there are errors in the .drl file, ant will complain that there are errors in my class even though the errors actually exist in the drl file? Right? Also, does this mean that I can tell ant to directly copy the rule files to the build folder since the java class is compiled by ant itself?

Comment: This means that any syntax errors in the .drl files will never be reported during compile time but only reported when the application is actually run, i.e at runtime? How do you check for syntax errors at compile time itself?

Comment: if you want to check DRL errors by compiletime, u need to run this code from antscript before you programm will be compiled. An handle situation if DRL-file has errors.

Comment: So basically, I have to write a utility class that will compile all drl files. This utility class should be run from the ant script. If any errors are found, then the script should report these errors, and as per my requirement, the build should fail!. The conclusion here is that .drl syntax errors can only be found at runtime and never at compile time (considering you are not using an IDE). Is this an assumption or a fact?

Comment: i don't understand yor conclusion: you run your utility at compile time, so any drl error will be found at COMPILE time (of you programm). P.S. If you use some imports in you rules, the utility tool should have of course them on classpath.

Comment: Lets go back to basics. consider a java source file named A.java. When you say javac A.java, if your source file has syntax errors, they will be reported at this stage. You will not be allowed to run the program by saying java A - unless you fix these errors. The solution provided above requires to "run" a Java class which will check for syntax errors in the .drl file. We may not be running our drools application as yet, but we are still checking for syntax errors in the drools file at "runtime" of our java utility!!. What would be ideal is a way to compile the .drl file directly!!!

Comment: If we leave ant aside for a bit and consider a simple drools application with one class calling the above code in the main method, I will never be able to find out if there are any syntax errors in my .drl file unless I run my drools application!

Comment: ah, you mean runtime of utility...yes that's correct. Anyway to compile it you need resolve imports, so compiler needs to know your classpath.

Comment: I had to use `DroolsObjectOutputStream` to get this working. Late comment, but hopefully it saves someone from debugging hours :)

Comment: For what exactly do you need it? Shuld i add it to code snippet?

Comment: Here's a [post](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-KnowledgeAgent-exception-while-trying-to-deserialize-KnowledgeDefinitionsPackage-td3064043.html#a3075412) that I followed in order to get my code working with `DroolsObjectOutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

There's a **drools-ant** jar in the droolsjbpm-tools zip.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how I can use this drools-ant.jar file to build my project (i.e compile java classes, .drl files and create an executable jar that can be run from the command line?